# I am not able access api's deployed in hostgator

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to deploy a spring boot application in hostgator javahosting with vps. I have generated jar file locally and deployed in server with "java -jar file.jar" application started successfully with no errors but not able to access  using ip of the server. I want to execute only jar file  and i have not installed maven.Any dependicies i am missing?permissions?

Comment: I want to know how can i confiqure with different ports, Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the server port to 8080 and it is up and running and able to access.